# galleria.js plugin and element.style issue

Tags: jquery-plugins, galleria

I have the galleria.js plugin working perfectly on local, but when I move it to the server the div that displays the images caption is set to `display:none;` via element.style.  I've tried setting `display:block !important;` in the stylesheet but to no avail.

Can an element.style be overridden in some other way? or any other suggestion that might help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed, I was applying the style to the wrong div (duh!).  It's working now.